# Installshield - Uninstall patch is not getting listed under Installed updates

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

I have read that i can create uninstallable MSP file. I have made the Allow Patch to be uninstalled checked while building the patch, but somehow the patch is not getting visible under Installed updates in the Program and Features screen.

Is there anything else i need to make the patch uninstallable?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because the installer was created use 'Traditional type MSI' Uninstallation of patch will only work with New Style MSI.